# Is there a way to disable Access 2007's Code editors CTRL+Y Shortcut key?

Tags: ms-access, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

## Background

I have used MS editors and applications for years including Visual Studio and office products and got use to <kbd>CTRL+Y</kbd> being redo. In fact so use to it doing that that I use undo <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> multiple times to look back on what I had just done then <kbd>CTRL+Y</kbd> until I get to my last point which has become second nature... that was until I came to Access 2007's VBA editor which has <kbd>CTRL+Y</kbd> being cut line.

Now I understand that this has always been this way (and I'm sure is useful if your use to it) but I'm not and apparently am unable to correct my brain just for Access 2007 and keep losing my whole redo list by clicking it when I want to redo. :(

I have looked for a solution in help files, Google (other search engines are available I'm sure! ;)) and even on SO but alas I have only found other soles like me who keep wiping there redo chain and others shouting at them for not being able to just learn that's what it does. LOL I'm stuck in my ways and don't use VBA's editor often enough to adapt!

## So my Question

Is it possible to ether:
* Remap the <kbd>CTRL+Y</kbd> shortcut key in Access 2007's VBA Code editor to Redo
* Disable the <kbd>CTRL+Y</kbd> shortcut key in Access 2007's VBA Code editor

Both of these would solve my problem of wiping the redo chain and losing any work I had done.

Comment: It is a while since I used MZ Tools but they were very popular and may still be. I do not know if it will provide an answer, but it may help: http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx

Comment: Thanks. That tool has helped a bit as it have managed to map the find function to CTRL+Y (redo isn't an option) although I had to uninstall the 64bit Office and install the 32bit one as it doesn't work on 64bit but not that bigger problem currently. BUT if anyone has a better option that work on 64bit office and/or allows redo to be mapped as well please add it as an option (also Remou if you add this as an option I will mark it as answered ;))

Comment: I will, because it may draw attention to you question again ;)

Comment: I can't upvote this enough..

Comment: I had the same issue with Excel VBA and this () seems to work for me: http://superuser.com/questions/879647/how-to-change-control-y-behavior-in-excel-vbas-ide/995949#995949

Comment: I hope the low number of upvotes here is because nobody uses the VBA editor and not because people don't care about the keyboard shortcut design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From comments:

It is a while since I used MZ Tools but they were very popular and may still be. I do not know if it will provide an answer, but it may help:

Comment: As above: Thanks. That tool has helped a bit BUT if anyone has a better option that work on 64bit office and/or allows redo to be mapped as well please add it as an option. If no other options are found I will mark this as the solution. :)